# Why android studio does not show the layout?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Why this still appear when I try the app on my phone it works very well but the preview not ?

help please.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN9rv.png

Comment: try change the Apptheme

Comment: i did that but i can not see the bar that include the app name in the preview but i see it in my phone so how to fix the preview??

Comment: this is mostly due to sdk configuration error.. checkout setting sdk and appropriate compileversion